# Does every Number from an SqlException has its own exception type

Tags: c#, .net, sqlexception

A SqlException has a Number property representing the actual exception.
A Duplicate Key Exception has for example the Number 2627.

Is there a type of Exception for this Number 2627? Or even wider asked are there any conrete types of exceptions for all the Numbers for an SqlException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are none. The `Number` is what can be used to differentiate fault reasons.

Comment: And the numbers are partof the SQL levl (error number) and documented tehre.